# How to find an unknown divider when only the answer and number to divide is known.

Tags: divisibility

I want to know if there’s a certain process that’ll give me this.
I’ve searched online, but since I can’t think of how to even ask the question, I’ve come here.
So an example would be: $\frac{60}{x}=4$ , find $x$
I know it’s probably simple but I just can’t think of anything
(I also have no idea what to tag it as, so sorry for miss tagging)

Comment: $x=60/4$, or $60=4x$.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for that. I can’t believe I didn’t realise that, am a little embarrassed at that. But again thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\begin{align}&\frac{60}x=4\\&60=4x\\&x=\frac{60}4\end{align}$$

**Edit**: Remember in other circumstances, if $x$ is found to be $0$ it must be ignored as $0$ cannot be on the denominator

Comment: It is important to note that x cannot be 0, because it is the denominator, and that if we get zero as an answer, we must ignore it.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for that. I can’t believe I didn’t realise that, am a little embarrassed at that. But again thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\frac{a}{x}=b$ has solution $x=\frac{a}{b}$... (provided $b$ is not $0$).

Comment: Thank you guys very much for that. I can’t believe I didn’t realise that, am a little embarrassed at that. But again thank you all :)